# pagination does not change page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am working on pagination for my website where i am displaying data from two tables on a database i have pagination in my page but it dose not behave as it suppose to behave it dose not change pages. currently i have 16 records displaying on the web page and have set `$config['per_page'] = 1;` the pagination bar goes up to 16 but it dose not flip through the pages all the records are displayed on the page. any help will be appreciated here is my code :

**controller**

```
 <?php

class Result_controller extends CI_Controller{

    function getall(){

        $this->load->model('result_model');
        $data['query'] = $this->result_model->result_getall();
        // print_r($data['query']); die();


        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Surva/index.php/result_controller/getall';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('tblanswers, credentials')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 1;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;


        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['records'] = $this->db->get('tblanswers, credentials', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(1, 0))->result_array();
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('result_view', $data);




        }


}

?>
```

**view**

```
   <div>    






     <table border="1">


      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Second Name</th>
         <th>Phone</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Answer</th>
         <th>Comment</th>
     </tr>
      <?php foreach ($query as $row): ?> 
     <tr>

         <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->second_name; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->phone; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
          <td> <?php echo $row->answerA;?>
          <?php echo $row->answerB;?>
          <?php echo $row->answerC;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->comment;?><br></td>

     </tr>

      <?php endforeach; ?>

     </table>  
     <?php if (isset($pagination))
      {
       echo $pagination;
      // echo "<pre>"; var_dump($query);
       } ?>
```

**model**

```
function result_getall(){

   return $this->db->select('tblanswers.*,credentials.*')
                         ->from('tblanswers, credentials')
                         ->get()
                         ->result_object();
```

Comment: Have you put limit in your query? Show your model code also.

Comment: the model is up its a simple get all function

Comment: That is the problem, the model needs to be limited and offset, see my answer.

Comment: check what $this->uri->segment(1, 0) returns..

Comment: try what @karmafunk suggests. I think it will work

Comment: no i am still getting errors

Comment: and unused variables $offset

Comment: YOu have three questions with the same topic littered in here why not ask a question once, this is just a matter of research i think your not doing your part

Comment: its a diferent question every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query doesn't magically know you only want x number of records. Codeigniter is going to display whatever you feed it from the model.

```
function getall(){

        $this->load->model('result_model');
        // print_r($data['query']); die();


        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Surva/index.php/result_controller/getall';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('tblanswers, credentials')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 1;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3; //guessing here, but this is where the uri segment you use to change pages goes.
        if($this->uri->segment('3')) {
        $offest = $this->uri->segment('3');
        } else {
        $offest = 0;
        }
        $data['query'] = $this->result_model->result_getall($config['per_page'],$offset);


        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['records'] = $this->db->get('tblanswers, credentials', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(1, 0))->result_array();
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('result_view', $data);




        }



Model:

function result_getall($limit=0,$offset=0){

   if($limit != 0)
   {
   return $this->db->select('tblanswers.*,credentials.*')
                         ->from('tblanswers, credentials')
                         ->limit($limit, $offset)
                         ->get()
                         ->result_object();
   } else {
   return $this->db->select('tblanswers.*,credentials.*')
                         ->from('tblanswers, credentials')
                         ->get()
                         ->result_object();
   }
```

Notice in the controller I'm passing the offset and the per page to the model, then using them to limit the returns in the model itself.

Comment: I think he uses this function to get all records to assign for $config['total_rows']. But he didnt do that also. He does nothing by getting the results of this query. somewhat confusing

Comment: True, sec I'll fix that, personally I would do this differently but I'm not rewriting all his code.

Comment: i edited my controller and model as your example now i am getting this error 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: offset

Filename: controllers/result_controller.php

Line Number: 20

any suggestions?

Comment: See edit, I didn't take into account you may not have a uri segment on page 1. I tend to pass the segment even on the base page to avoid this. Remember that uri segment has to match where your pagination creates it.

Comment: tnx for ur help i am getting couple of errors using your sugestion here are the errors : with curly brackets near else and 2 assignments used for veriambel $offset.

Comment: Typo, missed the closing bracket on the if. C'mon Edvinas, you need to read the code too...

Answer (score 0):

You should be looping through $records not $query.  $query contains all records.

Comment: can u give me an example as i am new to programming i daunt really undarstand tnx for posting

Comment: This is the basis of the answer but really amounts to "Google it" which isn't terribly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $limit = 10;

    $total = $this->legend_model->get_legend_count($language_id);

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'legend/index/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $total;
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;

    $config['first_link'] = '<< First';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last >>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next ' . '&gt;';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&lt;' . ' Previous';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<span class="number">';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</span>';

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<span class="current"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></span>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['offset'] = $offset;
    $data['legends'] = $this->legend_model->get_legend($language_id, $limit, $offset);

    $this->template->write('title', 'Legend : Manage Legend');
    $this->template->write_view('content', 'legend/index', $data);
    $this->template->render();
```