# pagination not working properly pages are not changing

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

hi i am new to codeigniter and trying to build a pagination function in my project it looks like everything works except the pagination is not changing the pages. daunt know what is wrong can anyone help me ? here is my code :

**controller**

```
class Result_controller extends CI_Controller{

    function getall(){

        $this->load->model('result_model');
        $data['query'] = $this->result_model->result_getall();
        // print_r($data['query']); die();


        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Surva/index.php/result_controller/getall';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('tblanswers, credentials')->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 1;
        $config['num_links'] = 10;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['records'] = $this->Result_model->result_getall($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('result_view', $data);
```

**model**

```
       function result_getall(){

  $this->db->select('tblanswers.*,credentials.*');
  $this->db->from('tblanswers');
  $this->db->join('credentials', 'tblanswers.answerid = credentials.cid', 'LEFT'); 
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();

    }
```

**view**

```
<?php foreach ($query as $row): ?> 
     <tr>      
         <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->second_name; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->phone; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
          <td> <?php echo $row->answerA;?>
           <?php echo $row->answerB;?>
           <?php echo $row->answerC;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->comment;?><br></td>

     </tr>

      <?php endforeach; ?>

     </table>  
     <?php if (isset($pagination))
      {
       echo $pagination;
      // echo "<pre>"; var_dump($query);
       } 
      ?>
```

Comment: Exactly same like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246189/pagination-does-not-change-page/15246467#comment21499253_15246467

Comment: this guy just made an account but the question and code are the same
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246189/pagination-does-not-change-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
Add this part to the controller

```
$page = $this->uri->segment(3);
if($page == '')
{
    $page = 1;
}
```

and modify this line

```
$data['records'] = $this->db->get('tblanswers, credentials', $config['per_page'], $page)->result_array();
```

EDIT:
change your model:

```
function result_getall()
{

    $this->db->select('tblanswers.*,credentials.*');
    $this->db->from('tblanswers');
    $this->db->join('credentials', 'tblanswers.answerid = credentials.cid', 'LEFT'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    //return $query->result();
    echo $this->db->last_query();

}
```

Comment: tnx for the answer but it did not change anything it still is performing in a same way. do u have any other suggestions ?

Comment: in your model please include `echo $this->db->last_query();` copy paste the results here and also paste the results in your phpmyadmin query field to see if you actually get any results

Comment: im sorry i daunt understand can u use more detail ?

Comment: I modified my first answer, replace your model function with the new one

Comment: SELECT `tblanswers`.*, `credentials`.* FROM (`tblanswers`) LEFT JOIN `credentials` ON `tblanswers`.`answerid` = `credentials`.`cid`

Comment: i tryed the query and it works fine

Comment: does that mean you have results or it didn't produce errors?
the above query doesn't have any pagination, it's only a join statement.

Comment: so how do i implement the pagination to it ?

Comment: i tried your example and i got these errors :  

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Result_model::result_getall(), called in C:\wamp\www\Surva\application\controllers\result_controller.php on line 8 and defined

Filename: models/result_model.php

Line Number: 5

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 2 for Result_model::result_getall(), called in C:\wamp\www\Surva\application\controllers\result_controller.php on line 8 and defined

Filename: models/result_model.php

Line Number: 5


A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: perPage

Filename: models/result_model.php

Line Number: 10

Comment: change the value by hand in the model, instead of passing the `$perPage` put `10`

Comment: nothing changed same errors are coming up.

Comment: copy the line calling the model please

Comment: $data['records'] = $this->YOUMODELNAME->result_getall($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3)); this line i copydit and pasted in the controller

Comment: `YOUMODELNAME` needs to be the name of your model with the first character UPPERCASE.

Comment: do i also need to inclode this part : $page = $this->uri->segment(3);
if($page == '')
{
    $page = 1;
} ?

Comment: i added the upper case and the same erorors are displayed. Do u have any more suggestions ?

Comment: please paste in the whole controller. I want to see how you are loading the models. thanks

Comment: i posted the controller for u its in my question

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
 function getall()
 {

    $this->load->model('result_model');
    $data['query'] = $this->result_model->result_getall();

    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/Surva/index.php/result_controller/getall';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('tblanswers, credentials')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $config['num_links'] = 5;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    /*
    CHANGE $this->YOURMODELNAME-> to the name of the model
    */
    $data['records'] = $this->YOUMODELNAME->result_getall($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('result_view', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
function result_getall($perPage, $page)
{

    $this->db->select('tblanswers.*,credentials.*');
    $this->db->from('tblanswers');
    $this->db->join('credentials', 'tblanswers.answerid = credentials.cid', 'LEFT'); 
    $this->db->limit($perPage, $page);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

I've put the part you need to modify in CAPITAL LETTERS. Let me know if this works out

Answer (score 0):

use limit function on sql query. for ex if you want to show 10 record on page use in sql query limit 0,10 first time

Comment: this i know the problem is that the all the records are dislayed ant the pagination is not funcioning right i think i need like an offset or something but i dount know how to inplement that

Comment: use this code to define offset, and load uri helper before use this method

$uri_segment = 3;
$offset = $this->uri->segment($uri_segment);